# C# WebSocket - Unable to connect to C# FleckWebSocket

Tags: c#, websocket, server

I can't connect to my WebSocket C# Server with a C# Application with websocket.

I have a server with Fleck Websocket Server.
Before Windows update my app connected to my server without problem. (Not sure if Windows update is the problem) But this update make me update the TLS of the server to TLS 1.2 .

This is the code that allowed me to connect to the server (before the bug) :

```
using (var socket = new ClientWebSocket())
                try
                {
                    
                    await socket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(string.Format("wss://myip:myport", ip, port)), CancellationToken.None);
                    webSocket = socket;                                         
                    server = string.Format("{0}:{1}", ip, port);
                    SocketConnected = true;
                    OnSocketStateChanged?.Invoke(socket, new SocketStateChangeEventArgs() { Server = string.Format("{0}:{1}", ip, port) });
                    await Receive(socket);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SocketConnected = false;
                    OnSocketStateChanged?.Invoke(socket, new SocketStateChangeEventArgs() { Server = string.Format("{0}:{1}", ip, port) });
                    Console.WriteLine($"ERROR - {ex.Message}");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
        } while (true);
```

I can still connect with a web application on my server and it works perfectly.

http://www.websocket.org/echo.html works too.

I tryied to change the connection method, so i have downloaded WebSocketSharp from nugget package for tryied another way to connect but it still doesn't work.

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://myip:myport"))
            {
                ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;
                ws.OnOpen += Ws_OnOpen;
                ws.OnClose += Ws_OnClose;
                ws.OnError += Ws_OnError;
                webSocket = ws;
                ws.Connect();
            }
```

My IP and Port are good, same values than the web Application.

I got no error in every case, but i'm still not connected, nothing on the server too.

My C# application works with .NET Framework 4.5.2.

No Firewall problem.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: can you try `WebSocketClient.SslConfiguration.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;` before you call ConnectAsyc() ?

Comment: There is no `SslConfiguration` in WebSocketClient.

Comment: How about `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped